# merging 2 binary trees- Easy

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to merge 2 binary trees, without worrying about making the resultant tree balanced. Here is my solution which does not work. Why are the Treenode ans and head set to 0 when they come back from merge functions. as i understand since TreeNode is not primitive type, head which points to ans should be updated with the resultant tree after call to merge function
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        
        
        
        TreeNode ans = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode head = ans;
        
        if(root1!=null && root2==null)
            return root1;
        else if (root1==null && root2!=null)
            return root2;
        else if (root1!=null &&root2!=null)
            merge (root1, root2,ans) ;   
            
            return head;
            
        
    }
    
    void merge (TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2,TreeNode ans)
    {
         if(root1!=null && root2==null)
            root2 = new TreeNode(0);
        
         else if (root1==null && root2!=null)
            root1 = new TreeNode(0);
         else if(root1==null &&root2==null)
         return;
        
            ans = new TreeNode(root1.val+root2.val); 
              merge(root1.left,root2.left,ans.left);
                merge(root1.right,root2.right,ans.right);          
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variables `head` and `ans` are not going to be updated like you expect them to. Java is [pass-by-value as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). This means that `ans` is a reference that you're passing the value of to the function `merge` and then overwriting over there.

You are also re-assigning the value of `ans` with every recursive call of `merge`. To return the correct value you would need to return the value assigned to that variable on the very first call.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Java passes references by value.**
Inside the method if you change the value of an attribute of the object that will work. But if you assign the pointer to a new object it will not chnage the original object